# C++ code works for some input, but doesn't on others

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code which will sort a user input array in ascending order (using quicksort) and uses a recursive function to find if a specific element in the array exists or not. My quicksort function works, but I'm struggling with getting the right answer for  recursivesearch function.

This is my main

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

using namespace std;
int recursivesearch(int arr[], int start, int end,int no);

int main () {
    int no,size;                            // 'no' is what element to search, should be 1 in this case
cout << "Enter what to search" << endl;          // element we need to search
cin >> no;
cout << endl;
cout << "Enter size of array" << endl;      // array size im testing is 8         
cin >> size;

int array[size];
for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    cin >> array[i];
}
if (recursivesearch(array,0,size-1,no)==0) {
    cout << "false" << " ";
} 
else {
    cout << "true" << " ";
}
cout << endl;

}
```

This is the recursive function

```
int recursivesearch(int arr[], int start, int end, int number) {
    int middle=0;            
    int element=number;
    int length=(end-start)+1;

    if (length%2!=0) {              // defining the size depending on if its even or odd
        middle=(start+end)/2;
    }
    else {
       middle=(start+end)/2+1;
    }

    if (arr[middle]==element){     // base case, if we find it, return the index
        return middle;
    }
    else if (length==1 && arr[middle]!=element) { // if we can't find it return 0
        return 0;
    }

    else if (arr[middle]>element) {
         recursivesearch(arr,start,middle-1,element); // if the middle index has value greater than element, call recursion for the left-hand side of the array from the middle point
    }
    else if (arr[middle]<element) { // if the middle index has value less than element, call recursion for the RHS from the middle point
        recursivesearch(arr,middle+1,end,element);
    }
}
```

I am only testing if number '1' is in the array as that's what I've been specified to do.
This only works for specific cases. If i write [-5 1 3 4 5 100 2014 7777] it works (shows true). But if I write [-5 0 1 3 4 5 100 2014 7777] I get segmentation fault. I don't understand how changing 1 number can lead to a segmentation fault. Can someone help me out?

Comment: `int array[size];` is VLA, which is not supported on C++ standard. In function `recursivesearch`, control reaches end of non-void function.

Comment: hmm can you elaborate on your second point more? I dont understand what you mean

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/EZJu1XCnHI7rbhxC